# unrecognized selector sent to instance in NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I searched a lot before posting this and tried many solutions and it didn't work, maybe there is something wrong in my code. It is basically a dice app, when i press the roll button it should animate the image in the view, but the problem is in the NSTimer which it is supposed to call the next method with an NSNumber parameter which is the result of arc4random() and it  shows the real image of the dice chosen

```
 `
ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end 

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize firstDie;
@synthesize secondDie;
@synthesize animation;
- (IBAction)rollButtonClick:(id)sender {
NSNumber* roll1 =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[self.model getDiceRoll]];
NSNumber* roll2 =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[self.model getDiceRoll]];
[self.firstDie randDie];
NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:roll1,@"Roll1Key",nil];
NSArray *info = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:roll1, nil];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showDie:)   userInfo:info  repeats:NO];
NSString *sum = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Sum = %d",[roll1 intValue]+[roll2   intValue]];
self.sumLabel.text = sum;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.model = [[Model alloc]init];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end`
```

showDie

```
-(void) showDie:(NSTimer*)num
{
if (self.dieImage == nil)
{
    self.dieImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
    [self addSubview:self.dieImage];
}
NSNumber *userInfo = num.userInfo;
NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"dice%d.png", [userInfo intValue]];
self.dieImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];}
```

randDie

```
 -(void) randDie
{
if (self.dieImage == nil)
{
    self.dieImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
    [self addSubview:self.dieImage];
}
UIImage *dieOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice1.png"];
UIImage *dieTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice2.png"];
UIImage *dieThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice3.png"];
UIImage *dieFour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice4.png"];
UIImage *dieFive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice5.png"];
UIImage *dieSix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dice6.png"];
NSArray *animate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:     dieFive,dieThree,dieOne,dieFour,dieSix,dieTwo, nil];
self.dieImage.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:animate duration:0.8];}
```

the app works and the image in firstDie keeps changing (for 2 seconds i suppose) then the app stops and the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" problem appears when -i think- it passes the parameter to showDie. Maybe i did not understand how to solve it (I am new to the Mac world and objective-C).please help.

the error message:

2013-07-25 02:13:40.550 test[3166:c07] -[ViewController showDie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8827830

2013-07-25 02:13:40.551 test[3166:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController showDie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8827830'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1e4bd 0x1c82bbc 0x1c8294e 0xb192c0 0x1c52376 0x1c51e06 0x1c39a82 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1bed7e3 0x1bed668 0x14ffc 0x252d 0x2455 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Post the actual, complete error message.

Comment: @rdelmar I just posted it

Comment: Hmmm... that's odd, it certainly looks like you have a showDie: method. Is all the code you posted in ViewController.m?

Comment: ViewController doesn't implement showDie:  I know you think it does, but you mucked up something somewhere.

Comment: i'll post the whole .m file

Comment: @rdelmar no the showDie and randDie are in DieWiew.m which is a subclass from UIView

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You need to set the target on your timer to  the instance of DieView rather than self.

Answer (score -1):

The userInfo: parameter of NSTimer is for you to supply a dictionary object. Your line:

```
NSNumber *userInfo = num.userInfo;
```

This will fail because the object `num` is a timer, and the userInfo object is actually an NSDictionary. The selector error you're having is probably when you call `intValue` on this object.

The correct course is to fold your NSNumber into an NSDictionary object first:

```
NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:roll1,@"Roll1Key",nil];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showDie:)    userInfo:info repeats:NO];

//in showDie
NSDictionary *info = num.userInfo;
NSNumber *roll1 = [info objectForKey:@"Roll1Key"];
NSInteger rollInteger = [roll1 intValue];
//continue...
```

Comment: "The userInfo: parameter of NSTimer is for you to supply a dictionary object" -- not true, it's typed as id, so you can pass any object.

Comment: my mistake. Guess I should have asked him to post the actual exception message